# Killing a Task manually in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

For testing / debugging purposes, is there an easy way to manually kill a task in a storm cluster? The best would be to enable it from storm-ui. Even if storm is supposed to reassign failed tasks, it would be good to test our code when it does happen.

Of course I can add a 'throw RuntimeException' in the code under some conditions to do so, but it needs manual coding, perhaps there is a function for that in the storm architecture?

Comment: Do you want to kill a worker of some topology or the topology?

Answer (score 2):

Tasks are logical units of work that are processed be executers. Executors are threads within a worker JVM. Thus, the only way to kill a single task manually (via kill in command line) would be to set the number of tasks equal to the number of executors (what is the default) and provide more workers than executors (ie, #workers > sum(dop of each spout/bolt). Having more workers than executors ensures, that a single executors run in each worker.

Comment: You are saying that the only way to test the event of storm reassigning tasks is to use a "storm rebalance" command? I am afraid of that as it is long to do so and difficult to automatize.

Comment: No. I guess there is a miss understanding. I was not referring to "storm kill" but to Linux "kill" to terminate a worker JVM manually.